# trigger a spacebar click on a textarea programatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a textarea

```
<textarea id="areadata" ng-model="mydata">{{data}}</textarea>
```

please how can I add a spacebar event on textarea immediately I click/trigger a button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="spaceevent">Add Space Bar Event</button>
```

I am trying to use this but not getting it right

```
$timeout(function() {
    angular.element('#areadata').triggerHandler('click');
  }, 100);
```

Comment: Do you want to trigger the `spaceevent` when someone hit the spacebar inside the textarea?

Comment: No I want to add the space data/ or rather spacebar when someone hits the spaceevent

Comment: I cannot understand, what does mean "trigger the spacebar"?

Comment: Example if I have helloworld If i click the button it becomes hello world. Something like that at the end of the text on the text area

Comment: If you don't care about the event, why not just suffixing your textarea string with " "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well this will add a space char to the textarea data when you hit the button:

```
app.controller('dummy', function($scope) {
  $scope.spaceevent = function () {
    $scope.mydata += " ";
  };
});

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="dummy">
  <textarea id="areadata" ng-model="mydata"></textarea>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="spaceevent()">Add Space Bar Event</button>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/d728rexy/)

Remember you need the `()` in an `ng-click` function so this is wrong: `ng-click="spaceevent"` while this is right `ng-click="spaceevent()"`

Comment: Angular IS Javascript

Comment: Please post your question